# Why did Michael "never take Joanna as a commuter"?

Tags: dialogue, the-commuter

At the end of [*The Commuter*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1590193/) (2018), Michael is back on the train station, and he approaches Joanna:

> Michael: The 6:20 every morning to Chicago, the 5:30 home, you know I never took you as a commuter.

Comment: Some context here would be useful but this seems more like an question about *English Usage* than movies?

Comment: @Paulie_D wouldn't that fall under dialogue explanation? That seems rather on-topic here? (still learning my way on M&TV)

Comment: It might **with context** but the OP hasn't provided any.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't seen the movie, so I may be missing some important context, but in general, saying "I never took you as **SOMETHING**" means "I didn't think you were interested in **SOMETHING**"

For example, "I never took you for a golfer" (after discovering that a person plays golf) means "I never thought you were the sort of person who'd enjoy playing golf."

So, based on what you've put in the question so far, I believe Micheal is saying he didn't think Joanna is the sort of person who would use public transportation (apparently having just found out she does so every day.)

Note: the term "commuting" does not *always* refer to public transit, but in this case as he's referencing train schedules, I would think it does.